# When form data is added to row automatically generate a drop down list in row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

So I have a function that will get the form event submission and move specific fields to a separate worksheet. Now I need to be able to add a drop down menu to the first row that contains some options IE.("NEW", "COMPLETE", "PENDING"). Is there a method for adding a drop down list to a cell via the function?

Here is my working code:

```
function AM2(e) {
  var form_name = "Form Responses 1";
  var open_name = "OPEN";

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(form_name);
  var open_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(open_name);

  open_ws.appendRow(['',e.values[1],'',e.values[2]]);
}
```

Based on what I found I thought I could use `SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['NEW', 'COMPLETE', 'PENDING'], true)`.

I was thinking that I could do something like this:

```
function AM2(e) {
  var form_name = "Form Responses 1";
  var open_name = "OPEN";

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(form_name);
  var open_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(open_name);

  open_ws.appendRow(open_ws.appendRow([SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['NEW', 'COMPLETE', 'PENDING'], true).build(),e.values[1],'',e.values[2]]);
}
```

But this does not work and causes an error. I cannot find any documentation that tells me how I can add a drop down at the same time I am appending rows to a sheet.

Maybe there is a way to grab the range of `appendRow()`. If I could get this I can probably work around this error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You won't be able to do this as part of `appendRow()`. You need to use `setDataValidation()` to achieve this, which has to be used on a `Range` object.

---

#### Solution:

Add the data validation rule straight after you append your row.

```
var row = open_ws.appendRow(['NEW',e.values[1],'',e.values[2]]).getActiveRange().getRow();

//set data validation
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['NEW', 'COMPLETE', 'PENDING'], true).build();
open_ws.getRange(row, 1).setDataValidation(rule);
```

As you can see, I've used your code to build the validation rule in `var rule`, then all we need to do is get the range of your newly-appended row using `getActiveRange().getRow()` on the append line and then set the validation using `setDataValidation(rule)`.

---

#### Reference:

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Comment: I thought about using the get last row however there is a problem when multiple submissions are submitted at once. sometimes the last row gets duplicated. Is it posible to get the row being worked by `appendRow()`? That would prevent duplication issues.

Comment: Wouldn't be possible inside `appendRow()` as far as I'm aware. However, if you want this validation to be applied on every entry why not just apply it to the whole column rather than doing it every time the form is submitted?

Comment: I will eventually be building some functionality that will automatically move the row to the completed tab when the drop down selection "COMPLETE" is selected. So I wanted to be able to handle all that in the function that is ran `onFormSubmit`. That said I could probably still do it in the entire row. By any chance is there a field that can set the default value to `NEW`?

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to detect what range `appendRow()` is currently appending?

Comment: @Mike-SMT well, I've learnt something new today! Just tried using `.appendRow().getActiveRange().getRow()` using `onFormSubmit` trigger and it returns the correct row for the append. I've updated the code in my answer, do you want to give it a try? PS: Also added in the default value of "NEW" for first object in your array.

Comment: Well that works until some row has been removed from the destination worksheet. So for example I sent 2 forms in and it all worked fine. I deleted the 2 rows from the destination worksheet and when I sent another form in the data posted to the correct row but the drop down went onto where the next row would have been if I had not deleted the others. I suspect the `getActiveRange()` is getting the range of where the data is in the form tab that is receiving the full data.

Comment: Yeah you're right - `getActiveRange()` is getting the active range in the form tab rather than this sheet. Aside from comparing the arrays or just setting validation for the whole column, I'm not sure how you'll be able to achieve this.

Comment: I am currently looking at `open_ws.getActiveRangeList()` to see if the other range is being recorded somewhere. Trying to get it to return an actual range and not the object name though.

Comment: Does it return two ranges or just the one?

Comment: I was not able to get it to show me what ranges were selected. It always just gave me the range object name.

Comment: I just tried this - it only returns 1 range, the same one from `.getActiveRange()`. I think you'll have to change your approach for this.

Comment: What method did you use to retrieve the range information?

Comment: Use `getRanges()` on your `rangeList` object, it returns an array of `Range` objects.